# Final element of list corrupted after removing an element

Tags: c++, list, fstream, ofstream

I'm having a weird issue. I'm writing a function to delete a line from a list of names created elsewhere, which, after some research, seems like it should be fairly simple. I write the current list of names into a list, display the list, have the user input the name they want to delete, remove the user-inputted name from the list, then display the updated list to the user.

Up to here, everything works perfectly, but when I write the list back into the file, the last name gets a random amount of characters chopped off of it, ranging from a couple of characters to the entire line. Now, this is where it gets strange. If I open the file and look at it without exiting the program, the last line of the file is messed up and continues to be whenever I display it later in the program. But, if I exit the program and then open the file, the last line is back to how it was originally written! That file is not written to again by the program after the list is written  in, so I cannot imagine why this is happening.

I almost decided that since the file ultimately comes out of the program correct, I could just ignore the issue, but I want the user to be able to view the list of names after the deletion for various reasons, which is made impossible while the last list item prints incorrectly.

I am still fairly beginner with C++, so I'm kind of hoping that this is just an issue of me not fully understanding lists or something. Regardless, dumbed down explanations would be ace.

I included the function below, any help is much appreciated.

```
char act, charname[50];
string namestr;
list <string> c1;
list <string>::iterator c1_Iter;

//write the names from the file into a list
ifstream names("List of Names.txt");
while (std::getline(names, namestr))
{
    c1.push_back(namestr);
}

//print the current names
cout << "Registered names:";
for (c1_Iter = c1.begin(); c1_Iter != c1.end(); c1_Iter++)
    cout << "\n" << setw(5) << " " << *c1_Iter;

//choose which names to delete and confirm
cout << "\n\nEnter the name you would like to delete: ";
cin.getline(charname, 50);
cin.getline(charname, 50);
cout << "\nAre you sure? Enter 'y' to permanently delete " << charname << ", and any other key to return to the start screen.";
cin >> act;

if (act == 'y' || act == 'Y')
{
    //delete a file associated with each name
    string strname(charname);
    strname.append(".txt");
    if (remove(strname.c_str()) < 0)
        perror("Error deleting file");

    else
    {
        //delete name from the file only if that person's individual file is successfully deleted
        c1.remove(charname);
        cout << "\n" << charname << " successfully deleted!\n";

        //print the updated list of names
        cout << "\nUpdated list of registered names:\n";
        for (c1_Iter = c1.begin(); c1_Iter != c1.end(); c1_Iter++)
            cout << *c1_Iter << endl;

        //write updated list of names over "List of Names" to update the file
        ofstream newNames("List of Names.txt");
        for (c1_Iter = c1.begin(); c1_Iter != c1.end(); c1_Iter++)
            newNames << *c1_Iter << endl;
        newNames.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before `ofstream newNames("List of Names.txt");` add a line `names.close()`

Comment: As @MohitJain has pointed out, the error seems to be the fact that `names` wasn't closed before you opened another file pointing to it. Did this fix it? If so, please close this question.

Answer (score 3):

As Mohit Jain mentioned in the comments, you need to call `names.close()` on the `ifstream` before opening the file for writing as a separate `ofstream`. Also, you can use a `std::string charname` rather than `char charname[50]`.

You could also use an `fstream` with appropriate seeking. If I'm not mistaken have active `ifstream` and `ofstream` objects handling the same file can lead to undefined behavior.

Here's a more C++ friendly solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    char act;
    std::string charname;
    std::string namestr;
    std::list<std::string> c1;
    std::list<std::string>::iterator c1_Iter;

    //write the names from the file into a list
    std::ifstream names("names.txt");
    while (std::getline(names, namestr))
    {
        c1.push_back(namestr);
    }

    //print the current names
    std::cout << "Registered names:";
    for (c1_Iter = c1.begin(); c1_Iter != c1.end(); c1_Iter++)
        std::cout << "\n" << std::setw(5) << " " << *c1_Iter;

    //choose which names to delete and confirm
    std::cout << "\n\nEnter the name you would like to delete: ";
    std::cin >> charname;
    std::cout << "\nAre you sure? Enter 'y' to permanently delete " << charname << ", and any other key to return to the start screen.";
    std::cin >> act;

    if (act == 'y' || act == 'Y')
    {
        //delete a file associated with each name
        std::string strname(charname);
        strname.append(".txt");
        if (remove(strname.c_str()) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error deleting file " << strname << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //delete name from the file only if that person's individual file is successfully deleted
            c1.remove(charname);
            std::cout << "\n" << charname << " successfully deleted!\n";

            //print the updated list of names
            std::cout << "\nUpdated list of registered names:\n";
            for (c1_Iter = c1.begin(); c1_Iter != c1.end(); c1_Iter++)
                std::cout << *c1_Iter << std::endl;

            //write updated list of names over "List of Names" to update the file
            names.close(); //Close the ifstream before opening the file for editing
            std::ofstream newNames("names.txt");
            for (c1_Iter = c1.begin(); c1_Iter != c1.end(); c1_Iter++)
                newNames << *c1_Iter << std::endl;
            newNames.close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I actually compiled and tested this on a small example and it worked.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but this would be a better answer if you explained the problem and your fix instead of just posting a code dump.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I appreciate your response. Hopefully the edit I just made clarifies things a bit better.